# FullCalendar: Block overlap when event.Title is same

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar that accepts external events, when you click the calendar an event is created, using `eventDrop` I block (`revertFunc()`) the addition of an event if the date is in the past, now I would also like to `revertFunc()` when the event being added or dropped matches an event that is already on that specific date. At first I was trying to compare `event.Title` but I can't find in the `eventDrop` parameters, any functions, or properties that house what is already there. I also looked at setting `overlap` to false but that won't work because I want to allow overlap in all cases except when duplicate.

Please see [Fiddle for example.](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/f730xg3L/) In this fiddle you can Add Product A to the same date over and over, if you un-comment the `eventOverlap: false` code then you can't drag product A or product B onto a date that already contains a product. Instead I need it to not allow a Drop/Add only if the date already contains the product you are trying to drop/add. I hope I am making sense.

```
<select id="productDd">
  <option selected="selected">Select Product...</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<div id="calendar">
</div>


var todaysDate = moment();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  theme: true,
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  selectable: true,
  eventDurationEditable: false,
  select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {
    if (end < todaysDate) {
      //block addition of dates to old calendars
      Alert("Sorry product order dates can not be added to days in the past.")
      return false;
    }
    var title, code, eventData;

    if ($('#productDd option:selected').text() == "Select Product...") {
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
      Alert("Please select a product from the drop down in order to add products to the calendar.");

    } else {
      title = $('#productDd option:selected').text();
      code = $('#productDd option:selected').val();
    }

    if (title) {
      eventData = {
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        className: title,
        productCode: code
      };

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
  },
  //eventOverlap: false,
  eventDrop: function(eventData, delta, revertFunc) {
    if (moment(eventData._start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') < todaysDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
      //block modification of old dates
      revertFunc();
    }
  },
  eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
  },
  editable: true,
  businessHours: {
    start: '7:00',
    end: '18:00',
    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  eventLimit: true
});
```

Thanks for looking at this with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using fullCalendars builtin functions: `selectOverlap` and `eventOverLap`

```
selectOverlap: function (event) {
    if (event.title === $('#productDd option:selected').text()) {
        alert("You may not add a duplicate event.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
    return stillEvent.title !== movingEvent.title;
},
```

[See FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f730xg3L/3/)